# How to change background color for a token in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'm trying customizing a token in VSCode in `settings.json` file:

```json
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "keyword.other.debugger.js.jsx",
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ea4462",
          "fontStyle": "italic bold",
          "background": "#ea4400",
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

But `background` isn't being recognized with the following warning message:

```
Token background colors are currently not supported.
```

There's any workaround? VSCode documentation is lacking about this issue.

Comment: I read you can use a textmate theme file also [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme), Maybe that has a way?

Comment: @TimothyG. no. and anyone who wants backgrounds for tokens should see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3429

Comment: in a perfect world, the answer at the dup target would be a generalized answer here, and I'd have dup-closed in the other direction, but alas